# 'Tuple' object has no attribute 'survived'

Tags: python, mysql, base-de-datos

Que tal amigos me encuentro haciendo un trabajo para la universidad pero no puedo encontrar la solucion de este problema, o tal vez lo estoy haciendo mal. Simplemente quiero importar un archivo csv a una base de datos usando Python, este es mi codigo completo:

```
import mysql.connector
import pandas as pd

#Conectores de MySQL
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
 host="localhost",
 user="root",
 passwd="2046",
 database= 'prueba_actividad'
)
mycursor = mydb.cursor()

#Uso de Pandas para importar archivo CSV
url = 'https://storage.googleapis.com/tf-datasets/titanic/train.csv'
data = pd.read_csv(url)
print (data)

for row in data.iterrows():
   mycursor.execute('''
   INSERT INTO prueba_actividad.dbo.Pasajeros2 (survived, sex, age, n_siblings_spouses, parch, fare, Clase , deck, embark_town, alone)
   VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
   ''',    
        row.survived,
        row.sex,
        row.age,
        row.n_siblings_spouses,
        row.parch,
        row.fare,
        row.Clase,
        row.deck,
        row.embark_town,
        row.alone)
   
   mydb.commit()
```

Cuando compilo mi codigo me lanza este error en la linea de row.survived y el error es: **Excepcion producida:'tuple' object has no attribute 'survived'**

No entiendo si lo estoy importando mal o que he hecho que esta mal, cualquier ayuda es bienvenida muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que `df.iterrows()` retorna tuplas (parejas) con dos valores, el primero sería el índice de la fila y el segundo sería ya el contenido de la fila. Ya que tú recoges todo sobre la variable `row`, esta variable es una tupla y en `row[0]` tendrías el índice y en `row[1]` la fila. Es decir, para acceder a los datos deberías poner `row[1].survived`, etc.

No obstante puedes cambiar la sintaxis del for a esto otro:

```
for indice, row in data.iterrows():
```

y así ya no tienes que tocar lo que va después. Es más, ya que la variable `indice` en realidad no la necesitamos para nada y la estamos ignorando, podemos seguir el convenio de llamarla `_` (una variable llamada `_` no tiene nada de especial para Python, es un nombre válido, pero es una ayuda para quien lee el código, quien al ver ese nombre sabe que la variable no es importante y no se usará).

De todas formas hay otro error. En el dataframe que has construido no hay ninguna columna que se llame `Clase`, por lo que `row.Clase` te dará otro error. El nombre de la columna era `class`, pero ésta es palabra reservada en python por lo que `row.class` tampoco te lo permitirá el compilador. Puedes usar la sintaxis alternativa `row["class"]` para acceder a una columna. Esa sintaxis no da problemas por ser `"class"` una cadena que puede contener cualquier valor.

En definitiva, tu bucle quedaría así:

```
for _, row in data.iterrows():
   mycursor.execute('''
   INSERT INTO prueba_actividad.dbo.Pasajeros2 (survived, sex, age, n_siblings_spouses, parch, fare, Clase , deck, embark_town, alone)
   VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
   ''',   
        (row.survived,
        row.sex,
        row.age,
        row.n_siblings_spouses,
        row.parch,
        row.fare,
        row["class"],
        row.deck,
        row.embark_town,
        row.alone)
        )
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por contestar @abulafia, ya lo he implementado a mi codigo como tu me indicas pero ahora me salta otro error, que tampoco se que puede ser. El mensaje de error es: **Excepcion Producida: execute() takes from 2 to 4 positional arguments but 12 were given**

Comment: Claro, es que toda la ristra de parámetros que le pasas a `execute()` deben ir en una tupla. No me di cuenta de ese detalle porque me había centrado en el problema con pandas, y porque no tenía una base de datos SQL para probar el código. He actualizado la respuesta.

Comment: Me funciono bastante bien y parece que me estoy acercando al resultado, pero ahora me arroja otro error que es: **Excepcion Producida: Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement** Me parece que es por utilizar `?` en vez de `%` pero no estoy seguro, lo implementare y aviso que tal.

Comment: Lo he implementado y me aparece otro error, que es : **1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.Pasajeros2 (survived, sex, age, n_siblings_spouses, parch, fare, class , deck, ' at line 1** A que se debe esto?